# Protege marks ontology inconsistent, however Hermit and Pellet Reasoner does not

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, reasoning

I am trying to run consistency check on an inconsistent ontology, for which Pellet and Hermit Reasoner is not giving an inconsistency.  However Protege successfuly marks the inconsistent classes.
In details, I am changing SBVR Rules to OWL 2.0.
So my rules are
It is necessary that car_rental is_insured_by at_least 3 credit_card;
It is necessary that car_rental is_insured_by at_least 5 credit_card;

The corresponding ontology is

```
Prefix( xsd:=<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> )
Prefix( ns:=<http://isd.ktu.lt/semantika/> )
Ontology( <http://isd.ktu.lt/semantika/s2o>
Declaration( AnnotationProperty( <ns:s2o#label_sbvr> ) )
Declaration( AnnotationProperty( <ns:s2o#label_en> ) )
Declaration( Class( <ns:s2o#car_rental> ) )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_sbvr> <ns:s2o#car_rental> "car_rental"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> <ns:s2o#car_rental> "car rental"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_en> <ns:s2o#car_rental> "car rental" )
ClassAssertion( <ns:s2o#car_rental> <ns:s2o#Car> )
Declaration( Class( <ns:s2o#credit_card> ) )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_sbvr> <ns:s2o#credit_card> "credit_card"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> <ns:s2o#credit_card> "credit card"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_en> <ns:s2o#credit_card> "credit card" )
ClassAssertion( <ns:s2o#credit_card> <ns:s2o#Credit> )
Declaration( ObjectProperty( <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> ) )
ObjectPropertyDomain( <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> <ns:s2o#car_rental> )
ObjectPropertyRange( <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> <ns:s2o#credit_card> )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_sbvr> <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> "car_rental is_insured_by credit_card"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> "car rental is insured by credit card"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_en> <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> "car rental is insured by credit card" )
SubClassOf( <ns:s2o#car_rental> ObjectMinCardinality( 3 <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> <ns:s2o#credit_card> ) )
SubClassOf( <ns:s2o#car_rental> ObjectMinCardinality( 5 <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> <ns:s2o#credit_card> ) )
)
```

Hermit and Pellet marks the ontology as consistent, where as Protege marks both classes as inconsistent.

Now if I take my SBVR Rules to be as follows

It is necessary that car_rental is_insured_by at_most 3 credit_card;
It is necessary that car_rental is_insured_by at_least 5 credit_card;

The corresponding ontology is

```
Prefix( xsd:=<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> )
Prefix( ns:=<http://isd.ktu.lt/semantika/> )
Ontology( <http://isd.ktu.lt/semantika/s2o>
Declaration( AnnotationProperty( <ns:s2o#label_sbvr> ) )
Declaration( AnnotationProperty( <ns:s2o#label_en> ) )
Declaration( Class( <ns:s2o#car_rental> ) )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_sbvr> <ns:s2o#car_rental> "car_rental"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> <ns:s2o#car_rental> "car rental"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_en> <ns:s2o#car_rental> "car rental" )
ClassAssertion( <ns:s2o#car_rental> <ns:s2o#Car> )
Declaration( Class( <ns:s2o#credit_card> ) )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_sbvr> <ns:s2o#credit_card> "credit_card"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> <ns:s2o#credit_card> "credit card"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_en> <ns:s2o#credit_card> "credit card" )
ClassAssertion( <ns:s2o#credit_card> <ns:s2o#Credit> )
Declaration( ObjectProperty( <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> ) )
ObjectPropertyDomain( <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> <ns:s2o#car_rental> )
ObjectPropertyRange( <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> <ns:s2o#credit_card> )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_sbvr> <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> "car_rental is_insured_by credit_card"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> "car rental is insured by credit card"@en )
AnnotationAssertion( <ns:s2o#label_en> <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> "car rental is insured by credit card" )
SubClassOf( <ns:s2o#car_rental> ObjectMinCardinality( 5 <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> <ns:s2o#credit_card> ) )
SubClassOf( <ns:s2o#car_rental> ObjectMaxCardinality( 3 <ns:s2o#is_insured_by__credit_card> <ns:s2o#credit_card> ) )
)
```

This time Hermit and Pellet both work perfectly fine, as does Protege.

I am attaching my Hermit code as well for reference,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Set;





import org.semanticweb.HermiT.Configuration;
import org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner;
import org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.ReasonerFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAxiom;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLDataFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLNamedIndividual;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.InconsistentOntologyException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.Node;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasoner;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasonerFactory;

import com.clarkparsia.owlapi.explanation.BlackBoxExplanation;
import com.clarkparsia.owlapi.explanation.ExplanationGenerator;
import com.clarkparsia.owlapi.explanation.HSTExplanationGenerator;

public class Demo {

    public void reason() throws OWLOntologyCreationException {
        // First, we create an OWLOntologyManager object. The manager will load and save ontologies.
        OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLDataFactory dataFactory=m.getOWLDataFactory();

        File inputOntologyFile = new File("C:\\Users\\1047785\\Desktop\\HermiT\\Input12.owl");
        OWLOntology o=m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(inputOntologyFile);// Now, we instantiate HermiT by creating an instance of the Reasoner class in the package org.semanticweb.HermiT.
        Set<OWLClass> cl = o.getClassesInSignature();
        //System.out.println(cl);




        ReasonerFactory factory = new ReasonerFactory();
        Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
        configuration.throwInconsistentOntologyException = false;
        OWLReasoner reasoner=factory.createReasoner(o, configuration);
        BlackBoxExplanation exp=new BlackBoxExplanation(o, factory, reasoner);
        HSTExplanationGenerator multExplanator=new HSTExplanationGenerator(exp);
        for (OWLClass c : cl) {
            System.out.println(c);
            System.out.println(reasoner.isSatisfiable(c));
            Set<Set<OWLAxiom>> explanations = null;
            try {
            explanations =multExplanator.getExplanations(c);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            /*for (Set<OWLAxiom> explanation : explanations) {
                System.out.println("------------------");
                System.out.println("Axioms causing the unsatisfiability: ");
                for (OWLAxiom causingAxiom : explanation) {
                    System.out.println(causingAxiom);
                }
                System.out.println("------------------");
            }*/
                continue;
            }
            for (Set<OWLAxiom> explanation : explanations) {
                System.out.println("------------------");
                System.out.println("Axioms causing the unsatisfiability: ");
                for (OWLAxiom causingAxiom : explanation) {
                    System.out.println(causingAxiom);
                }
                System.out.println("------------------");
            }

        }
```

I am at a loss for this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "working fine" do you mean in all three places you can see `car_rental` as unsatisfiable?

In the first ontology, it should not be unsatisfiable: `minCardinality 3` and `minCardinality 5` are not incompatible restrictions: an individual with five values for the property will satisfy both.

`minCardinality 5` and `maxCardinality 3` (in your second example) are not compatible, instead: there is no number of values that will satisfy both. So in the second ontology `car_rental` should be unsatisfiable, and if you have individuals of that class the ontology is inconsistent.

Comment: Yes all three of them give unsatisfiable in the second case. 
In case of the first ontology then why does Protege marks it as unsatisfiable?
Since my SBVR Rules are contrasting, I was hoping my ontology will do the same, Is there no way, to achieve unsatisfiability in the first ontology?

Comment: Which reasoner is Protege using in the first case? Protege does only very limited inferences on its own, it relies on a reasoner for most complex inferences, like this would be.

Comment: Sounds like a bug there, either in protégé use of pellet or in pellet itself.